# Set value of variable upon link click

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, variables, hyperlink

I currently have a `listview` on an ASP.NET webpage that displays "cottage" records from an Access database. The name of each cottage is displayed as a hyperlink so when clicked brings you to another webpage:

```
<li style="">Name:
     <asp:Hyperlink ID="Cottage_NameLabel" NavigateURL="~/Cottage.aspx"
         runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Cottage_Name") %>' />
     <br />
```

This works perfectly fine when selecting a hyperlink. What I want the system to do is to set the value of a publically declared variable (set in a module) to the `Cottage_Name` of the selected hyperlink. So say if i clicked on a hyperlink that said "cottage1", the public variable is set to "cottage1" and then the navigate URL opens the next webpage.

Would really appreciate it if anyone could help me do this!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by setting a variable (is it something you can accomplish by passing value in querystring, etc)? You can't set a server variable without AJAX or some type of postback.

Comment: I'm trying to set the variable so that when the page (that is loaded when the hyperlink is selected) is brought up, i can use an sql query that selects a record where the name of the cottage is equal to the value of the variable i am trying to set and then display the result on the page. Sorry if i haven't made it very clear, i'm very new to ASP web development

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a **[LinkButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.aspx)** instead of a Hyperlink... Catch the click event and do whatever you want...

For instance:

```
<asp:LinkButton  ID="Cottage_NameLabel" runat="server"  Text="whatever" onclick="Cottage_NameLabel_Click" />
```

Then in CodeBehind:

```
    protected void Cottage_NameLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)sender;
        Session["MyCottageName"] = btn.Text;
        Response.Redirect("Cottage.aspx");
    }
```

In your Cottage.Aspx page you can check the value of the Session variable like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["MyCottageName"] != null)
        {
            string name = (String)Session["MyCottageName"];
            ... 
        }
```

Comment: forgot to mention i'm doing it in vb.net, but i'm sure i'll be able to work out how to do it in vb, will let you know how it goes thanks!

Comment: Try [this](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) - it usually does a good job converting C# to vb.net

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the name as a querystring variable to the page. If you go this route, you need to make sure you URL encode the cottage name:

```
<a href='/Cottage.aspx?name=<%# Server.UrlEncode(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Cottage_Name")) %>'><%# Eval("Cottage_Name") %></a>
```

And then on cottage.aspx you can get the cottage name:

```
Dim cottageName As String = Request.QueryString("name")
```

This would be preferable to a button or other postback solution as it removes the need for a postback and then a redirect.